# Keep getting this error message for my RockPaperScissor Program. How do I fix this error?

Tags: java, jgrasp

this is the error message

```
 ----jGRASP exec: javac -g RockPaperScissorRandom.java

RockPaperScissorRandom.java:40: error: variable computerPlay might not have been initialized
      **System.out.println("Computer play is: " + computerPlay);**
                                                ^
1 error

 ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

this is the program

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class RockPaperScissorRandom{
   public static void main(String[]args){

      String personPlay; //User's play -- "0", "1", or "2"
      String computerPlay; //Computer's play -- "0", "1", or "2"
      int computerInt; //Randomly generated number used to determine computer's  play

      String response;

      Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
      Random generator  = new Random();

      System.out.println("Hey, let's play Rock, Paper, Scissors!\n" + "Please enter a move.\n" + "Rock = 0, Paper = 1, and Scissors = 2.");

      System.out.println();

      //Generate computer's play (0,1,2)
      computerInt = generator.nextInt(3)+1;

      //Translate computer's randomly generated play to //string using if //statements

      if (computerInt == 1)
         computerPlay = "0";
      else if (computerInt == 2)
         computerPlay = "1";
      else if (computerInt == 3)
         computerPlay = "2";

      //Get player's play from input-- not that this is stored as a string
      System.out.println ("Enter your play: ");
      personPlay = scan.next();

      //Make player's play uppercase ofr ease of comparison
      personPlay = personPlay.toUpperCase();

      //Print computer's play
      System.out.println("Computer play is: " + computerPlay);

      //See who won. use nested ifs

      if (personPlay.equals(computerPlay))
         System.out.println("It's a tie!");
      else if (personPlay.equals("0"))
         if (computerPlay.equals("2"))
         System.out.println("Rock crushes scissors. You WIN!!");
      else if (computerPlay.equals("1"))
         System.out.println("Paper eats rock. You LOSE!!");
      else if (personPlay.equals("1"))
         if (computerPlay.equals("2"))
         System.out.println("Scissors cuts paper. You LOSE!!");
      else if (computerPlay.equals("0"))
         System.out.println("Paper eats rock. You WIN!!");
      else if (personPlay.equals("2"))
         if (computerPlay.equals("1"))
         System.out.println("Scissors cuts paper. You WIN!!");
      else if (computerPlay.equals("0"))
         System.out.println("Rock breaks scissors. You LOSE!!");
      else
         System.out.println("Invalid user input.Computer wins by default. You LOSE!!");
   }
}
```

Comment: i bolded the error line and the location of the error has asterisks left and right of the line

Comment: The compiler down know that all possible code paths will initialise the variable, because it doesn't understand the range of values for `computerInt` (or indeed for any library)

Comment: Use: `computerPlay = Integer.toString(generator.nextInt(3)+1);` Remove all user of `computerInt` and any other assignment to `computerPlay`.

Answer (score 1):

Either assign empty String / null to it:

```
String computerPlay = null;
```

or

```
String computerPlay = "";
```

You could also modify your code a little bit instead:

```
if (computerInt == 1)
    computerPlay = "0";
else if (computerInt == 2)
    computerPlay = "1";
else /* removed if (computerInt == 3)*/
    computerPlay = "2";
```

That way your computerPlay variable will always get initialized.

The error is shown since after following code:

```
computerInt = generator.nextInt(3)+1;
```

computerInt is equal to 1 or 2 or 3, but compiler doesn't now that. nextInt() method could return anything from compiler's point of view.

Answer (score 1):

This mean that  computerPlay may has not been initialized.
Your are doing this :

```
if (computerInt == 1)
     computerPlay = "0";
  else if (computerInt == 2)
     computerPlay = "1";
  else if (computerInt == 3)
     computerPlay = "2";
```

but there is no default value for computerPlay in the case he doesnt fit in any case so the value would be garbage and make your program crash. To let your program compile.
You can either add a default value to computer Play like this :

```
String computerPlay = "";
```

or adding an other else in your if statement that will be a default value.

```
if (computerInt == 1)
     computerPlay = "0";
  else if (computerInt == 2)
     computerPlay = "1";
  else if (computerInt == 3)
     computerPlay = "2";
  else
     computerPlay = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize variables in their declaration statements if there's no guarantee that they will be initialized later in the program.
For example, your if/else-if statements don't ensure that computerPlay will be initialized because there's a chance that none of the if/else-if statements will be executed. To fix this, change this line of code,

```
String computerPlay;
```

to this

```
String computerPlay = "";
```

There is an exception to this. When variables are declared outside the subrountine/method that they are being used in, then they don't have to be initiazlied

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting that error is because it is possible (in the compiler's view, anyway) that 'computerPlay' does not get a value. The only time `computerPlay` gets assigned is here:

```
if (computerInt == 1)
   computerPlay = "0";
else if (computerInt == 2)
   computerPlay = "1";
else if (computerInt == 3)
   computerPlay = "2";
```

But what if `computerInt` is 4? Or 0? Or -273? The compiler doesn't know that you've limited the values to 1, 2, and 3, so it assumes it's possible for any other number, meaning that `computerPlay` might not get initialized.

To fix this, either change the last `else if` to simply `else`, or assign a default value to `computerPlay` in its definition... i.e., `int computerPlay = 0;`